# Resource for practicing algorithms without programming? (migraine sufferer)

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, algorithms, resource-information

Does there exist a resource for exercises and problems of the form "design a program with the following specifications in time/space O(f(n))"?

I am aware of competitive programming websites but i can't currently program due to migraines. I can't practice off these websites because often the best solution is some exponential algorithm which I will have no way of knowing whether it will work without implementing it.

CLRS is a good resource for problems but there aren't enough to practice on a regular basis. I would like a resource preferably of the computer contest flavor but where I can practice on pen and paper rather than programming it.

Alternatively, how can I make the most of programming contest problems so that I can practice algorithms with pen and paper without implementing anything?

Comment: How would you check the correctness/performance of your algorithm? It's not that you can't learn to drive without getting in a car, but it's not going to be easy and any facsimile is likely going to be imperfect at teaching you all the required skills. I'd almost expect that having to manually and mentally test your algorithm at every turn would be as much of a burden; but I can't make that judgment on your behalf.

Comment: Talk to a doctor about your migraines. For some versions there are easy solutions. See: https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/ocular-migraine.htm, for example.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between time complexity and your health situation (migraines). A lot of O(n) solutions are very difficult to derive, some not, and same for exponential algorithms. Usually the best solution in most competitive programming sites is not exponential.